# android - Использование векторного изображения в виджете

Tags: android, изображения, vector, виджет, app

Здравствуйте, подскажите, возможно ли использование векторных изображений в виджетах на рабочий стол? Простейший layout для виджета с imageview с app:srcCompat просто не показывает изображение; с android:src изображение выводится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас случайно наткнулся на ответ, в библиотеке поддержки AppCompat в версии 23.3 они убрали поддержку векторных изображений, связано с какой-то ошибкой. В версии 23.4 поддержку векторных изображений восстановили. Сейчас новейшая версия 24.2.1 и в ней векторные изображения заработали только когда я поменял обычный ImageView на AppCompatImageView. Причем заработали только в Activity, виджет всё еще высыпается с ошибкой.

UPD: наконец-то нашелся способ. Всё-еще, если задавать картинку в xml разметке для виджета, то она не показывается в виджете. Но если задать её программно, то всё работает как часы, примерно так:

```
RemoteViews widgetViews = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);
widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.vectorImage);
```

UPD: setImageViewResource работает для более старших версий, на 4.3.1 Android всё еще проблемки